# Doing a PROPFIND on only some resources in a WebDAV collection?

Tags: webdav

Let's say I have 10 resources at `https://example.com/webdav`. If I do a PROFIND on it it will return the 10 resources. However, what if I want to retrieve the properties of only 2 resources in there (since I know their names)? Is it possible to specify this? I read the WebDAV spec but couldn't find if it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no standard way to do this.